# How to append ' on the generated SQL insert statement in Java

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I'm creating a program that will create a file and write SQL insert statements. I noticed that when a string contains apostrophe ('), it will be written incorrectly on the SQL insert statement.

How to replace this string in Java?

Example: John Doe don't need to attend his brother's wedding.

Into: 'John Doe don''t need to attend his brother''s wedding.'

The SQL Insert Statement should be like this:

```
Insert into TABLE (NAME,REASON) values ('John Doe','John Doe don''t need to attend his brother''s wedding.');
```

It is currently written as:

```
Insert into TABLE (NAME,REASON) values ('John Doe','John Doe don't need to attend his brother's wedding.');
```

Comment: Use prepared statements: https://www.adobe.com/support/ultradev/database/prepared_statements/prepared_statements02.html

Comment: Always use parametrized queries

Comment: As Bart and Serhat already stated: use prepared statements, so _DO NOT_ append the parameters to the query directly. Prepared statements will handle conversions for you and that will also increase security since attempts at SQL injection will get thwarted due to those conversions/escaping.

Comment: Do **not** append user input to SQL strings. Learn to properly use `PreparedStatement`. See [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html) or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Comment: So the question is: why are you creating an SQL file. Is this necessary? As other comments explain, it's better to insert directly and use a prepared statement. Or if you want to batch-load data, some CSV format is probably supported by your database. So why the SQL file?

Comment: @RealSkeptic - the sql file will be used and run into another database that's why I'm creating a sql file with insert statements.

Comment: Which database, why can't you connect to it directly, and why can't you use CSV files?

Comment: @RealSkeptic - it's Oracle DB. I had to use replaceAll("'","''") to achieved this. thanks for your inputs.